# Accessing local blob storage from WP8

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone-8

I am trying to download a photo which is stored in my local azure blob storage from my developing WP8 app. The blob container is set to have public access to anyone. Host computer firewall is turned off and my WP8 app can access my WebApi.

For example, the blob url is http:// 127.0.0.1 :10000/devstoreaccount1/photos/1.jpg. 
Obviously, 127.0.0.1 is not accessible from the WP8 app. So I am replacing 127.0.0.1 to 192.168.0.3 (my host LAN ip). But somehow, I can't access the file. It returns 404 exception.

Anyone knows how to access the blob file in local azure blob storage?

Cheers,
LD

Answer (score 0):

You can change the binding parameters of Storage Emulator.

If you are using the latest version of Azure SDK (2.x), the location of Storage Emulator Config file is:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\Storage Emulator\WAStorageEmulator.exe.config`

Related configuration section of this file is:

```
<services>
  <service name="Blob" url="http://127.0.0.1:10000/"/>
  <service name="Queue" url="http://127.0.0.1:10001/"/>
  <service name="Table" url="http://127.0.0.1:10002/"/>
</services>
```

Later in this file you can also find the devstoreaccount1 setting, where you can see and/or change the key also.

I would however be careful when editing this file and keep all original settings on a safe place.
Once you change these settings [CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.cloudstorageaccount.developmentstorageaccount.aspx) will no longer work. And you will have to provide actual Azure Storage connection string pointing to the new Address!

On other trick is to use a [PortMapper application](http://www.analogx.com/contents/download/network/pmapper/freeware.htm). I have been using this since ages to quickly solve issues like the one you mention. It is extremely simple TCP port mapper, where you configure the source IP Address (say 192.168.0.13), Destination IP Address (127.0.0.1) and Port (10000). It has been working for me (and clients) like a charm and helps me avoid editing files.